# Ошибка о циклических зависимостях бинов невсегда происходит

Tags: java, spring

В spring-boot приложениях имеется циклическая зависимость ServiceA -> ServiceB -> ServiceC -> ServiceA. Но при запуске main метода через IDE или gradle bootRun exception о циклических зависимостях не происходит, но при запуске через java -jar происходит. Почему циклические зависимости не определяются в первых случаях и все работает?

Comment: Циклическая зависимость порождает рекурсию, так что иксепшен не должен выскакивать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Циклические зависимости между бинами не всегда приводят к ошибке - потому что конструирование бинов идет в несколько этапов. Но если потом пытаться подключать аспекты например, или что-то их использующее - например Java Melody - то тогда ошибку Вы получите. Лучше сразу не допускать циклических зависимостей в коде.